# В каком слове правописание суффикса определяется правилом: «В  суффиксах отымённых прилагательных

Tags: орфография

В каком слове правописание суффикса определяется правилом: «В 
суффиксах отымённых прилагательных -ЕНН-, -ОНН-/-ЁНН- пишется НН»? 
1) военной 
2) жизненную 
Вопрос поставил в тупик .1)Образованно от слова война 2)от слова жизнь . 
Распишите подробно ответ.

Answer (score 4):

1) воен/н/ой  -суфф -Н-, а не -енн-
2) жизн/енн/ую - правильный ответ

Comment: Решают ГИА на завтра. Варианты выложены в сети.

Comment: Что удивительно: все спрашивают - и никто не ищет готовый ответ.

Comment: Ищут. В сети есть и ответы. Кстати, с ошибками.

Comment: Я в курсе, что это к ГИА, но меня подкупило "распишите подробно". Значит, человек хочет ЗНАТЬ, а не списать. Похвально.

Comment: Он хочет, чтобы это-кого-то подкупило. Тот, кто хочет знать, набирает вопрос в поисковике.

Comment: Все может быть. Дело в том, что в ответах, выложенных в Сети, именно на этот вопрос ответ неверный. Там выбирают почему-то слово "военный". Немудрено, что  ребенок, который не просто списывает, а сам прорешивает варианты и думает, засомневался.